# AsyncTaskでプログレスバーを追加したらプログレスバー以降の処理が異様におそくなりました。原因は？

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask

ご無沙汰しています。
わからないところが出てきてしまったのでまた戻ってきてしまいました。

twitter4jを用いて自作のTwitterクライアントアプリにプログレスバーの処理を追加してみたところ
プログレスバーの次にはタイムラインの取得をおこなっているのですがその処理が異様に遅く、表示される時もあるのですが、ずっとぐるぐる30秒以上していることの方が多いです。
この遅いのを速くしたいのですが何かいい方法はないでしょうか？
はじめはスレッドを考えていましたが、エラーが出てAsyncTaskに変更しないといけないところまではわかりましたが、その後がどうしていいのか分からず立ち往生しています。
よろしくお願いします。

### プログレスバー部分のソース

```
//timeline
private void reloadTimeLine() {


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //タスク開始
            Log.d("TAG_ASYNCTASK", "onPreExecute");
            // プログレスダイアログの設定
            waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // プログレスダイアログのメッセージを設定します
            waitDialog.setMessage("NOW LOADING...");
            // 円スタイル（くるくる回るタイプ）に設定します
            waitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            // プログレスダイアログを表示
            waitDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {
          /*try {
            return mTwitter.getHomeTimeline();
          } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }*/


            int page = 1;
            ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> tl = null;
            int total = 0;


            while (true) {
                Paging paging = new Paging(page++,COUNT_MAX);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    if (tl == null) {
                        tl = mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
                    } else {
                        // 現在のトータル数を保持
                        total = tl.size();

                        tl.addAll(mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging));
                    }
                 // 全部取得出来たら終了
                    if (tl.size() == total) {
                        break;
                    }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // APIのキャパオーバーじゃなければ続行
                    if (RATE_LIMITED_STATUS_CODE != e.getStatusCode()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
               // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //  // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return tl;



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {

            if (result != null) {

                mAdapter.clear();
                for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(status);
                }
                getListView().setSelection(0);
                if (waitDialog.isShowing()){waitDialog.dismiss();}

            } else {
                showToast("タイムラインの取得に失敗しました。。。");

            }
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

### 全体のソース

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {

private TweetAdapter mAdapter;
private Twitter mTwitter;
private long rt_id=0;
private static final int RATE_LIMITED_STATUS_CODE = 400;
private static final int COUNT_MAX =200;
private static ProgressDialog waitDialog;
//private Thread thread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (!TwitterUtils.hasAccessToken(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwitterOAuthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {

        mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(this);
        mAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    final int position, final long id) {
                //リストビューのクリックを有効
                final Status item = (Status) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //username取得
                final String user ="@"+ item.getUser().getScreenName() ;
                //RT文取得
                rt_id =item.getId();

                //showToast(String.valueOf(rt_id));
                //popup-menu
                final CharSequence[] items = {"返信","全員へ返信", "RT","このtweetをお気に入り登録する"};

                final AlertDialog.Builder listDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                listDlg.setTitle(user+"さんへどうする？");
                listDlg.setNegativeButton("閉じる",null);
                listDlg.setItems(
                    items,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // リスト選択時の処理
                            // which は、選択されたアイテムのインデックス
                            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tweet, null);
                            Button btn =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.action_tweet);
                            //@Userでテキストセット
                            final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            //switch-case
                            switch(which){
                            case 0:
                                //showToast((String) items[0]);
                                //返信
                                editText.setText(user +" ");
                                //カーソルを@user+1文字分移動する
                                editText.setSelection(user.length()+1);

                                //ボタン表示

                                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        if(dialog != null){
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }

                                        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
                                            @Override
                                            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                                                try {
                                                    // 返信
                                                    mTwitter.updateStatus(params[0]);

                                                    return true;
                                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                                if (result) {
                                                   showToast("返信しました");
                                                   editText.setText("");
                                                } else {

                                                    showToast("返信できませんでした");

                                                }
                                            }
                                        };
                                        task.execute(editText.getText().toString());
                                    }


                                });

                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle(user+"へ"+(String) items[0])
                                    .setView(view)
                                    .setPositiveButton( "返信をやめる", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        } }) .show();

                                break;
                            case 1:
                                //全員へ返信

                                UserMentionEntity[] ume = item.getUserMentionEntities();
                             if(ume != null){

                                List<String> reply = new ArrayList<String>();
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                for(int i=0;i<ume.length;i++){
                                    UserMentionEntity replyall=ume[i];
                                    reply.add("@"+replyall.getScreenName());
                                    sb.append("@"+replyall.getScreenName()+" ");

                                }


                                String[] replies = ( String[] )reply.toArray( new String[0] );
                                String userall=user+" "+ new String(sb);
                                editText.setText(user+" "+ new String(sb));
                                editText.setSelection(userall.length());
                                //showToast(String.valueOf(userall.length())+"文字");

                             }

                          btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if(dialog != null){
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }



                                    AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
                                        @Override
                                        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                                            try {
                                                // 返信
                                                mTwitter.updateStatus(params[0]);


                                                return true;
                                            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                             dialog.dismiss();
                                            if (result) {
                                               showToast("返信しました");
                                               editText.setText("");
                                            } else {

                                                showToast("返信できませんでした");

                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    task.execute(editText.getText().toString());
                                }


                            });

                          final AlertDialog.Builder listDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                          new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle((String) items[1])
                            .setView(view)
                            .setPositiveButton( "返信をやめる", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                } }) .show();


                                break;
                            case 2:
                                //RT
                                AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean> rt = new AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean>(){
                                    @Override
                                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                        try{
                                            mTwitter.retweetStatus(params[0]).getId();

                                            return true;
                                        } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                     @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                             dialog.dismiss();
                                            if (result) {
                                               showToast("公式RTしました");
                                            } else {
                                                showToast("公式RTできませんでした");
                                            }
                                        }
                            };
                                rt.execute(rt_id);

                                break;

                            case 3:
                                //  お気に入り
                                AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean> fav = new AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean>(){

                                    @Override
                                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                        try {
                                            mTwitter.createFavorite((params[0])).getId();
                                            return true;
                                        } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            return false;
                                        }


                                    }
                                     @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                             dialog.dismiss();
                                            if (result) {
                                               showToast("tweetをお気に入り登録しました");


                                            } else {

                                                showToast("tweetをお気に入り登録できませんでした");

                                            }
                                        }


                            };
                            fav.execute(item.getId());
                            break;
                            }


                        }


                    });

                // 表示

                listDlg.create().show();
            }

        });



       reloadTimeLine();
        }
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        reloadTimeLine();
        showToast("更新しました");
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_tweet:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TweetActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_reply:
        showToast("リプライ一覧を取得します。");
        replyTimeLine();
        showToast("リプライ一覧を正常に取得しました。");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



//Twitterのつぶやき部分のレイアウト
private class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TweetAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tweet, null);
        }

        Status item = getItem(position);
        //UserName
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(item.getUser().getName());
        //@xxx(userID)
        TextView screenName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.screen_name);
        screenName.setText("@" + item.getUser().getScreenName());
        //本文
       TextView text=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);


        //Replyあるときに@xxxの部分を変更

        String str = item.getText();


        /*if(str.indexOf("@")!=-1){
            String x_user ="@"+item.getInReplyToScreenName();
            UserMentionEntity[] ume = item.getUserMentionEntities();
             if(ume != null){
                List reply = new ArrayList();
                for(int i=0;i<ume.length;i++){
                    UserMentionEntity replyall=ume[i];

                    reply.add(x_user);
                    if(str.indexOf(x_user)!= -1){
                        int start = str.indexOf(x_user);
                        int end = x_user.length();
                        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(str);
                        BackgroundColorSpan span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.argb(50, 184, 101, 204));
                        spannable.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        text.setText(spannable);
                    }else{
                        text.setText(item.getText());
                    }


                }

                String[] replies = ( String[] )reply.toArray( new String[0] );


            }


        }
        else{ */
            text.setText(str);
       //   }


        //Userのアイコン
        String iconUrl =item.getUser().getProfileImageURL();
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(iconUrl).into(icon);
       //RTした人のユーザアイコン取得
        ImageView rt_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rt_icon);
        if(item.isRetweet()){
            String rtUrl =item.getRetweetedStatus().getUser().getProfileImageURL();
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(rtUrl).into(rt_icon);
            rt_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            rt_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //Userの画像をタイムラインに表示

        MediaEntity[] mediaEntitys = item.getExtendedMediaEntities();
        ImageView media1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView media2=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView media3=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView media4=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);



        if(mediaEntitys !=null){
            List list = new ArrayList();

            for( int i = 0; i < mediaEntitys.length; i ++ ){
                MediaEntity mediaEntity = mediaEntitys[i];
                String mediaURL = mediaEntity.getMediaURL()+":small";
                list.add(mediaURL);
            }
            String[] medias = ( String[] )list.toArray( new String[0] );

            switch(mediaEntitys.length){
            case 1:
                media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                break;
            case 2:
                media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[1]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media2);
                break;
            case 3:
                media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[1]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media2);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[2]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media3);
                break;
            case 4:
                media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                media4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[1]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media2);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[2]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media3);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[3]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media4);
                break;
            default:
                media1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            }


        }else{
            media1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            media2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

private void replyTimeLine(){
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResponseList<Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResponseList<Status>>(){

        @Override
        protected ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                Paging paging = new Paging();
                paging.setCount(10);
                return mTwitter.getMentionsTimeline(paging);
            }catch(TwitterException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                mAdapter.clear();
                for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(status);
                }
                getListView().setSelection(0);

            } else {
                showToast("自分宛ての返信が取得できませんでした。。。");

            }
        }
    };
    task.execute();

    }

//timeline
private void reloadTimeLine() {


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //タスク開始
            Log.d("TAG_ASYNCTASK", "onPreExecute");
            // プログレスダイアログの設定
            waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // プログレスダイアログのメッセージを設定します
            waitDialog.setMessage("NOW LOADING...");
            // 円スタイル（くるくる回るタイプ）に設定します
            waitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            // プログレスダイアログを表示
            waitDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {
          /*try {
            return mTwitter.getHomeTimeline();
          } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }*/


            int page = 1;
            ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> tl = null;
            int total = 0;


            while (true) {
                Paging paging = new Paging(page++,COUNT_MAX);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    if (tl == null) {
                        tl = mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
                    } else {
                        // 現在のトータル数を保持
                        total = tl.size();

                        tl.addAll(mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging));
                    }
                 // 全部取得出来たら終了
                    if (tl.size() == total) {
                        break;
                    }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // APIのキャパオーバーじゃなければ続行
                    if (RATE_LIMITED_STATUS_CODE != e.getStatusCode()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
               // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //  // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return tl;



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {

            if (result != null) {

                mAdapter.clear();
                for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(status);
                }
                getListView().setSelection(0);
                if (waitDialog.isShowing()){waitDialog.dismiss();}

            } else {
                showToast("タイムラインの取得に失敗しました。。。");

            }
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}





private void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}






}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(100);`はもともと存在したものですか？

Comment: いつも有難うございます。
`Thread.sleep(100);`はネットで調べてセットだと思い追加したものです。

Comment: 追加したのであれば、0.1秒間待機するという命令がループの中で最大200回呼ばれているので、本来の処理時間より最大20秒遅くなるように思います。おそらく一度に大量のページを取ってしまうと多分APIリミットに引っかかるので追加することを考えたのではないかと思いますが…。

Comment: 有難うございます。
恐らくおっしゃるとおりだと思います。
`ツイートの取得数(COUNT_MAX)を変更`したり`while（true）{}`の条件を変更してもダメでした。
いっそのことプログレスバーの部分の処理を消すと一瞬だけうまくいく時もありますが、新規ツイート画面を表示して戻ろうと思うと空白で表示されたのでその可能性が高いと思います。
くるくるの処理は諦めstreaming等の処理に切り替えたほうがよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 一度にCOUNT_MAXまでツイートを取得するのではなく、APIリミットに引っかからない程度に取得して、リストビューが最下部まで移動されたらまたデータを追加で取得する…というのが一般的な実装ですね。

Comment: 有難うございました。
一度それでやってみます。

Comment: 解決しました！有難うございました。
一番下に来たら追加する処理にも挑戦してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにて解決致しました。
quesera2さんに感謝致します。
有難うございました。

`while(true){}`の条件を`while(page<3){}`に変更することでぐるぐるした処理がそれなりの時間でできるようになりました。
ソースコードは以下のようになりました。

```
//timeline
private void reloadTimeLine() {


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //タスク開始
            Log.d("TAG_ASYNCTASK", "onPreExecute");
            // プログレスダイアログの設定
            waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // プログレスダイアログのメッセージを設定します
            waitDialog.setMessage("NOW LOADING...");
            // 円スタイル（くるくる回るタイプ）に設定します
            waitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            // プログレスダイアログを表示
            waitDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {
          /*try {
            return mTwitter.getHomeTimeline();
          } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }*/


            int page = 1;
            ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> tl = null;
            int total = 0;


            while (page<3) {
                Paging paging = new Paging(page++,COUNT_MAX);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    if (tl == null) {
                        tl = mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
                    } else {
                        // 現在のトータル数を保持
                        total = tl.size();

                        tl.addAll(mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging));
                    }
                 // 全部取得出来たら終了
                    if (tl.size() == total) {
                        break;
                    }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // APIのキャパオーバーじゃなければ続行
                    if (RATE_LIMITED_STATUS_CODE != e.getStatusCode()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
            return tl;



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {

            if (result != null) {
                if (waitDialog.isShowing()){waitDialog.dismiss();}
                mAdapter.clear();
                for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(status);
                }
                getListView().setSelection(0);


            } else {
                showToast("タイムラインの取得に失敗しました。。。");

            }
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```